# Select2 - Show all results at the beginning but start filtering after 4 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

What I want to achieve with select2 is to have all the options visible when clicking the select (wich is the default behaviour) but only filter the results when there is 3 or more characters in the input field.

I can add a minimum characters required with the minimumInputLenght option but I lost the initial listing of the options.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a [matcher](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#matcher).

I have defined a matcher as follows:

```
matcher: function(term, data) {
    // If less than 3 characters are typed return all of the data
    if (term.length < 3) {
        return data;
    }

    // 3 or more characters typed so perform filter
    return data.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) == 0;
}
```

`term` is the characters typed in and `data` is the data that we are checking against. The length of `term` is checked and if it is less than 3 then we return this `data` item (as we want all items to be displayed). Otherwise (i.e. 3 or more characters typed) we check whether the `data` item contains the `term` typed and return it if true

Please see [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3aLzqp4/2/) for a demo. When 3 or fewer characters are typed it displays the full list. When more than 3 characters are typed if performs the filtering.